# Visual studio: Debug C++ application started as external process from C#

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging

Sorry for noob question.
I have 2 projects in VS solution: c# gui and unmanaged c++ console application. C++ application is started as external process from C# with some arguments. Is there any way to start debugging c++ app directly after starting process in C#?

I know about Command Arguments in c++ debugging, but sometimes it's uncomfortably.

Comment: You can try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Or you can Call https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/k4wx2tde.aspx in your c++ code